# IoS scripting - using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios

https://github.com/ThisIsBenny/iOS-Widgets/blob/main/car-location/car-location.js

This application looks to use javascript to pipe data to a application?

Where on earth is the documentation for this? This is a awesome feature.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking for the documentation link?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be JavaScript code that can be used on iPhone within ´Scriptable App’.
It contains documentation and link to ECMASCRIPT 6 with is the JavaScript used.
With Scriptable, you can create widget that can be run from Safari in share menu, and many other things. Alll r’this in JavaScript.